# What is the size of Number data type in Oracle PL\SQL with out precision and scale suplied?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

One of the guidelines in my new project is to specify precision & scale along with the NUMBER in Oracle PL\SQL. The developer handbook says if this is not specified a default size of 22 bytes is allocated for every variable.

While I understand it is important to specify precision & scale where ever possible. I don't seem to agree that 22 bytes are allocated if the precision is not supplied.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1834

From the Oracle documentations:

"**Internal Numeric Format**

Oracle Database stores numeric data in variable-length format. Each value is stored in scientific notation, with 1 byte used to store the exponent and up to 20 bytes to store the mantissa. The resulting value is limited to 38 digits of precision. Oracle Database does not store leading and trailing zeros.
For example, the number 412 is stored in a format similar to 4.12 x 10<sup>2</sup>, with 1 byte used to store the exponent(2) and 2 bytes used to store the three significant digits of the mantissa(4,1,2). Negative numbers include the sign in their length."

I sent the above documentation to the database architect, but he doesn't seem to agree with me.

If we don't specify precision & scale for a NUMBER datatype in oracle pl\sql will it take 22 bytes or just enough bytes to store the value assigned to it?

Comment: I don't understand. Are you asking about numbers in a PL/SQL program, or what is stored in a table in an Oracle (SQL) database? You mention PL/SQL several times, but you link to an Oracle Database document. And the two answers you got so far are about what is stored in the database. I am not sure about the memory allocation for PL/SQL, but I certainly HOPE it does the allocation at compile time (dynamic memory allocation is time-consuming). If it does, then indeed it allocates memory based on your declaration, not on the actual values used. If so, your developer's guide is correct for PL/SQL.

Comment: @mathguy sorry I was referring to the PL\SQL. But the vsize test suggested by Husqvik in the below answer seems to be still valid.

Comment: Actually, no. @Husqvik's answers shows you the internal storage format for numbers (how the number is stored ON DISK, or how it would be stored if you were to save it). What PL/SQL does with number declarations is that it allocates MEMORY (not disk storage) - completely different concepts. I wasn't able to find documentation for the PL/SQL memory allocation mechanism, but where it does use dynamic memory allocation, namely for long varchar2 variables, there is a lot of talk about that. It is almost certain that memory for numbers is allocated statically.

Comment: Which means, if you don't provide precision and scale, the compiler must assume "worst case" and allocate the max, even if you know - in your program - that that's not needed. So when you write PL/SQL programs you need to think about precision and scale, even though in most applications in the database (SQL, for storage) you don't since storage, unlike memory, is allocated dynamically, based on the actual numeric value.

Comment: @mathguy Because Oracle PL/SQL documentation (I'm aware of) mentions nothing about memory management dynamics of `number` data type I simply assume programmer has no control over it. This also means it doesn't matter if you define your numbers `number(1)` or `number(38)` - the memory foot-print will be the same. My memory test also seems to verify this (PGA changes always identical and independent on number precision). All of the above also means that OP's developer handbook is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

`NUMBER` is equivalent of `NUMBER(*)`. Precision and scale are only restrictions for accepted values and have no impact of the memory allocation.

```
HUSQVIK@HQ_PDB_TCP> DECLARE
  2      item_count CONSTANT NUMBER := 10000000;
  3      TYPE t_collection IS TABLE OF NUMBER(38);
  4      data t_collection := t_collection();
  5
  6      PROCEDURE print_allocated_memory IS
  7          allocated_memory NUMBER;
  8      BEGIN
  9          SELECT
 10              value INTO allocated_memory
 11          FROM
 12              v$statname
 13              JOIN v$mystat ON v$statname.statistic# = v$mystat.statistic#
 14          WHERE
 15              name = 'session pga memory';
 16
 17          dbms_output.put_line('Allocated memory: ' || round(allocated_memory / 1048576, 1) || ' MB');
 18      END;
 19  BEGIN
 20      print_allocated_memory;
 21
 22      data.extend(item_count);
 23
 24      print_allocated_memory;
 25
 26      FOR i IN 1..item_count  LOOP
 27          data(i) := 1.00000000000000000000000000000000000011;
 28      END LOOP;
 29
 30      print_allocated_memory;
 31  END;
 32  /
Allocated memory: 3.5 MB
Allocated memory: 483.8 MB
Allocated memory: 483.8 MB

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:01.04
HUSQVIK@HQ_PDB_TCP>
```

You can experiment with NUMBER constraints and see that it makes no difference on memory allocation The memory is allocated before any value is actually set and it doesn't change after that. In the example one entry in the collection is approximately 48 bytes but I expect some significant overhead of collection entry itself.

Associative arrays and nested tables allocate the same space (so I expect the nested table internally to be implemented same as associative array which is B-tree), with VARRAY I got to 410 MB so it's slightly more efficient (and faster too).

Comment: Does this apply to **PL/SQL**?

Answer (score 1):

> but he doesn't seem to agree with me.

Show him a documentation of `vsize` function: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions213.htm#i80071

> **VSIZE** returns the number of bytes in the internal representation of
>   expr. If expr is null, then this function returns null.

And simply prove him that 412 occupies 3 bytes, while -412 takes 4 bytes:

```
select vsize( 412), vsize( -412) from dual;
VSIZE(412)                             VSIZE(-412)
---------- ---------------------------------------
         3                                       4
```

Another test proves that @Husquick's answer is true:

```
select vsize( 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000011 ), 
       vsize( 1.00000000000000000000000000000000000011)
from dual;
VSIZE(0.0000000000000000000000000000000 VSIZE(1.0000000000000000000000000000000
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
                                      2                                      21
```

Comment: Does this apply to **PL/SQL**?

Comment: @user272735 if you think that this anwers is not usefull in this case, then please downvote it.